# Проблема с запуском edit

Tags: windows, cmd, edit

Пользуюсь постоянно компонентом microsoft : edit , который может создавать и редактировать файлы любого типа .. 
В качестве редактора html css js я его использовал 
Делал это так :

```
cd desktop 

md sites 

md css js img 

cd.>index.html

cd css

cd.>style.css

cd..

cd js 

cd.>app.js

cd..

edit idex.html
```

после того как выполнял команду edit index.html всегда открывался компонент windows edit но что то вчера произошло в системе после чего перестал работать edit, **каким образом решить эту неприятность ?**

задал вопрос на [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-edit-does-not-work/75ef0441-1f62-423f-9879-5b520ee3e42a?tm=1518837082582) и ответ появился сразу я сделал как мне было сказано но это не помогло ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "перестал работать edit" - это что значит?

Comment: @Igor извените, сейчас вставлю скриншот проблемы

Comment: https://www.wintips.org/how-to-fix-ntvdm-encountered-a-system-error-when-running-16bit-apps-windows-10-solved/

Comment: @Igor  дополнил , включено

Comment: @Igor так же сделал по инструкции , зашёл в Совместимость приложений и отключил... ответ дополнил скрином

Comment: @Igor  в общем вся инструкция на wintips не помогла , всё сделал от верха этого сайта и до самого низа ... в общем фиг с ним .. буду в st3 делать